# Can I reduce the money to be spent during my visit to the uk for that was why I was denied visa

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I was refused a uk visitors visa because the money I stated to be spent on my travel was higher than my last salary received. And also I’m a continuing student and gave no documentation on next semester’s course term and start date. I was also told I intend to visit the uk for tourism for 1 month six days, what does that mean ?
How do I address all these please

Comment: Please post a copy of the refusal letter (with personal information blacked out). It is very important to see the actual text of a UK visa refusal.

Comment: You can reduce it somewhat, but they're going to expect the amount to be credible. Just saying your trip will cost less isn't that helpful, because it still costs a certain amount to buy plane tickets, find accommodations, buy food, etc... Building up your savings is likely a better plan. But please post a copy of the refusal letter so we can see the whole picture.

Comment: Reducing the amount you intend to spend could just be seen as a ploy to try to get your application approved, especially if the change doesn’t correspond with your stated itinerary/plans for the trip. If you’re a continuing student, all you have to do is provide evidence of your attendance to date and your ongoing enrolment. The reference to the purpose and length of your visit can only be related to the information you stated in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Tourism is a luxury. Tourists pay money for happy memories and pictures.

Economic illegal immigration is an investment. Workers pay money for the chance to earn more money later on.

To be **credible** as a tourist, your tourism expenses must be an amount you can reasonably afford as a luxury. This is not just a question of money in your bank account, it is a question of the balance between income and expenditure.

If someone else pays for your tourism, it must be credible for them to pay that much.